# Получить ресурс из папки Assets

Tags: android

В папке assets есть две папки img и audio. В папке img есть подпапка figures с картинками в формате png.

Как получить ресурс из этой папки? Т.е. мне нужно в переменную типа int записать идентификатор ресурса.

P.S. если картинки в папке res/raw то понятно как:

```
Resources resources = MainActivity.this.getResources();
int resId = resources.getIdentifier("image1", "raw", MainActivity.this.getPackageName());
```

А вот с папкой assets как?

Вот код моего фрагмента: Но почему-то не выводится картинка и не проигрывается звук

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_LETTER = "letter";
    public static final String ARG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String ARG_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String ARG_AUDIO = "audio";

    int mSound;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        TextView txtLetter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLetter);
        ImageView imgLetter = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgLetter);

        txtLetter.setText(args.getString(ARG_LETTER));
        imgLetter.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAssets(ARG_IMAGE));

        play(ARG_AUDIO);

        imgLetter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                play(ARG_AUDIO);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(String filename) {
        AssetManager assetManager = this.getContext().getAssets();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("img/alphabet/" + filename + ".png");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    void play(String filename) {

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getContext().getAssets().openFd("sound/alphabet/" + filename + ".mp3");
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
            {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    //При готовности к проигрыванию запуск вывода звука:
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
            {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос вместо изменения этого.

Answer (score 1):

У `assets` нет идентификатора ресурса. Только так, как к файлу можно обращаться:

```
InputStream  inputStream = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("img/figures/figure1.png");
```

Comment: Это я знаю. Я думала можно можно как-то получить id как из папки raw

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос. Если у меня картинки хранятся в папке assets и мне нужно их выводить в ImageView как это делать?

Comment: `BitmapFactory` вам поможет декодировать `InputStream`, дальше все обычно. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
try {
        // Получаем входной поток
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("figures/" + "ic.png");
        // Загружаем изображение
        Drawable pict = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // Задаем изображение ImageView
        ImageView my_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_img);

        my_img.setImageDrawable(pict);
    }
    catch(IOException ignored) {
    }
```

Если обработка будет происходить во фрагменте то перед сторокой `getAssets` пропишите `getActivity`

```
InputStream ims = getActivity().getAssets().open("figures/" + "ic.png");
```

Comment: Кто поставил минус, пожалуйста разъясните чем мой ответ заслужил минус? Это проверенный мною и рабочий метод.

Comment: Я не минусовал, но вижу за что могли: потоки за собой закрывать надо.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, простите, я бы узнатб хотел, а как поток закрыть? Добавить блок `finally` и в нем что-то типа `ims.close()`? Или лучше сам `InputStream` добавить в `try(сюда)`?

Comment: @Flippy, как здесь рекомендуют: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, спасибо )

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja все понял)